# How to take a screenshot using Cordova plugin for Android?

Tags: android, cordova

How to take a screenshot using Cordova plugin for Android? Not only take the home App screenshots it will be taken all other App's screenshot also.
Please advise.

Comment: Please refer this :https://www.npmjs.com/package/com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've used the Cordova screenshot plugin it works well. but what's the client requirement is when closed the home app and open the other app in the device then we have to take the screenshot. Please advise

Comment: Sorry but is actuallly not possible with cordova. In fact i can't affirm isn't possible in android, so the only way for you is to develop you'r own plugin.